# Reactjs - add/remove item from array and store using checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

**Prerquisite**

I'm fetching a list of accounts (Ajax request) which I display on page load (with a checkbox next to them). By default all the accounts are selected and added to the store (redux).

**Goal**

Add/remove accounts from array & store (redux) when checkbox are checked/unchecked:

- checbox is checked --> add account to array & store
- checkbox is unchecked --> remove account from array & store

**Logic**

I created two separate actions & reducers:

- one to manage the checkbox status
- one to manage the addition/removal of the account to the array &
  store

When testing my code, it works fine at the beginning but eventually the accounts added/removed are not correct. The issue must be in savingAccount() but not sure what I'm doing wrong?

**My code**

Pre-populating data to the store in ComponentWillMount():

```
  componentWillMount = () => {
    let defaultAccount = this.props.account
    let defaultCheckbox = this.props.checkboxStatus

    for(let i =0; i < this.props.products.arrangements.items.length; i++){
      const data = {}
      data['id'] = i
      data['isSelected'] = true
      data['sortCode'] = this.props.products.arrangements.items[i].sortCode
      data['accountNumber'] = this.props.products.arrangements.items[i].accountNumber
      data['accountName'] = this.props.products.arrangements.items[i].accountName
      defaultAccount = defaultAccount.concat(data)

      const checkboxesArray = {}
      checkboxesArray['id'] = i
      checkboxesArray['checked'] = true
      defaultCheckbox = defaultCheckbox.concat(checkboxesArray)
    }

    this.props.addAccount(defaultAccount)
    this.props.toggleCheckbox(defaultCheckbox)
  }
```

Displaying list of accounts from Ajax response (this.props.products.arrangements.items)

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {typeof(this.props.products.arrangements.items) !== 'undefined' &&
       (Object.keys(this.props.account).length > 0) &&
       (typeof(this.props.checkboxStatus) !== 'undefined') &&
       (Object.keys(this.props.checkboxStatus).length > 0) &&
       (Object.keys(this.props.products.arrangements.items).length > 0) &&
        <div>
          {this.props.products.arrangements.items.map((item,i) =>
            <div className="accountContainer" key={i}>
              <Checkbox
                required
                label={"Account Number "+item.accountNumber+" Product Name "+item.accountName}
                value={true}
                checked={this.props.checkboxStatus[i].checked === true? true: false}
                onChange = {(e) => {
                  this.toggleChange(this.props.checkboxStatus[i])
                  this.saveAccount(e, i, item.accountNumber, item.accountName)
                }}
              />
                </div>
          )}
        </div>
      }
      </div>
  )
}
```

Updating isSelected value when checkbox is checked/unchecked:

```
saveAccount = (e, i, accountNumber, productName) => {
  const data = {};
  data['id'] = i
  data['accountNumber'] = accountNumber
  data['productName'] = productName

  if(this.props.checkboxStatus[i].checked === true){
    let accountArray = Array.from(this.props.account)
    accountArray[i].isSelected = true
    this.props.addAccount(accountArray)
  }
  else {
    let accountArray = Array.from(this.props.account)
    accountArray[i].isSelected = false
    this.props.addAccount(accountArray)
  }
}
```

Reducer

```
function Eligible(state = { products: {}, account: [], checkboxStatus: [] }, action){
  switch (action.type){
    case ADD_PRODUCTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        products: action.data
      }
    case ADD_ACCOUNT:
      return {
        ...state,
        account: action.data
      }
    case TOGGLE_CHECKBOX:
      return {
        ...state,
        checkboxStatus: action.data
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Actions

```
export const ADD_PRODUCTS = 'ADD_PRODUCTS'
export const ADD_ACCOUNT = 'ADD_ACCOUNT'
export const TOGGLE_CHECKBOX = 'TOGGLE_CHECKBOX'

export function addProducts(data){
  return {type: ADD_PRODUCTS, data}
}

export function addAccount(data) {
  return { type: ADD_ACCOUNT, data}
}

export function toggleCheckbox(data) {
  return { type: TOGGLE_CHECKBOX, data}
}
```

Updating checkbox status:

```
  toggleChange = (checkbox) => {
    let toggleCheckbox = this.props.checkboxStatus
    toggleCheckbox[checkbox.id].checked = !checkbox.checked
    this.props.toggleCheckbox(toggleCheckbox)
  }
```

Comment: Could you show your actions and how you're dispatching them? Also, in `saveAccount` regardless of the checked state you're adding the account, is that correct? `this.props.addAccount(removeAccountState.accounts)`

Comment: Just updated my question with my actions. In saveAccount I have a condition, only add if checkbox checked and only remove if checkbox unchecked if(this.props.checkboxStatus[i].checked === true)( ...) else(){ ... }

Comment: Maybe, your actions and state are not synchronized. Add please toggleChange code also.

Comment: Thanks, you're trying to store the state of accounts in local state and in redux. In my experience this leads to problems when things get out of sync. Either stick to 100% redux, or 100% local state. Don't try and mix the two

Comment: Just updated my question with toggleChange()

Comment: It looks like you're modifying the state directly (`const removeAccountState = this.state` and `removeAccountState.accounts = filteredAccounts`), then calling `setState` after.  Since `setState` is asynchronous, could that be causing your state to get out of sync between calls?  Also in toggleChange you are updating just the checkboxes state, but in saveAccount you are updating the entire state (accounts and checkboxes), possibly overwriting your earlier checkboxes-only update?

Answer (score 1):

I think the asynchronicity of `this.setState` is probably causing an issue.

`this.state` contains both `accounts` and `checkboxes`:

```
this.state = {
  accounts: [],
  checkboxes: []
}
```

In your change event handler, you call two functions:

```
onChange = {(e) => {
    this.toggleChange(this.props.checkboxStatus[i])
    this.saveAccount(e, i, item.accountNumber, item.accountName)
}}
```

First toggleChange:

```
toggleChange = (checkbox) => {
    let toggleCheckbox = [...this.state.checkboxes];

    toggleCheckbox[checkbox.id].checked = !checkbox.checked
    this.setState({
        checkboxes: toggleCheckbox
    })

    this.props.toggleCheckbox(this.state.checkboxes)
}
```

You're updating the checkboxes property of the state (via this.setState) - all good there.  But on the last line, you're passing `this.state.checkboxes` out.  Since this.setState is async, this will likely *not* reflect the changes you just made (you could send `toggleCheckbox` instead).

The next function called in the event handler is saveAccount, which contains (partially):

```
const addAccountState = this.state

if(this.props.checkboxStatus[i].checked === true){
    addAccountState.accounts = addAccountState.accounts.concat(data)
    this.setState(addAccountState)
    this.props.addAccount(addAccountState.accounts)
}
```

Here you're taking the current value of this.state (which may be old due to the async setState).  You update the .accounts property of it, then send the whole thing (which includes `.accounts` and `.checkboxes`) to `this.setState`.

Since the `.checkboxes` state may have been old (the previous `this.setState` may not have fired yet), this would queue up the old .checkboxes state to overwrite the new state you tried to save in `toggleChange()`.

A quick and dirty fix there could be to use `this.setState({accounts: addAccountState.accounts})` instead, but there may be other issues floating around too (like the modifying of `this.state` properties directly).

> Because setState is asynchronous, subsequent calls in the same update
>   cycle will overwrite previous updates, and the previous changes will
>   be lost.

[Beware: React setState is asynchronous!](https://medium.com/@wereHamster/beware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous-ce87ef1a9cf3)

---

Regarding the separation of store and state... one option might be to not store the checkboxes separately at all, but rather compute them based on which accounts are selected.

It will depend on the needs of your application of course, so I'll be making a few assumptions for the sake of example...

- Your application needs a list of selected accounts
- Your component needs to show a list of *all* accounts
- Your component has checkboxes for each account: checked = selected = part of application's 'selected accounts' list.

In this case, I would have the list of selected accounts passed in via `props`.

Within the component I would have the list of all accounts in the local state (if your 'all accounts' list is passed in via props already, then just use that - no local state needed).

Within the render function of the component, I would compute whether the checkbox should be checked or not based on whether or not the account exists in the 'selected accounts' list.  If it exists, it's checked.  If not, not checked.

Then when the user clicks to check/uncheck the box, I would dispatch the function to add or remove the account from the 'selected accounts' list, and that's it.  The account would be added or removed, which would cause your props to update, which would re-render your component, which would check or uncheck the boxes as appropriate.

That may not jive exactly with your particular application's needs, but I hope it gives you some ideas!  :)

Comment: Right I see, so the asynchronicity of this.setState might be causing the issue. How would you update the code to only use the store?

Comment: I'm assuming that the data from the store is being passed into this component via its `props`, correct?  If so, you would just remove the local state from the component and base it on the `props` data instead.  Modifications would be done by dispatching the functions that modify the redux data (which would then update the `props` and cause the component to re-render).  That said, if data only applies to one component, it doesn't necessarily need to be in redux (local state is fine).  But if you have data in redux, don't keep the same data in local state and try to sync them - just use redux.

Comment: I've updated my question with my latest code, as suggested, I'm now only using the store (redux) to avoid out of sync issues but I'm still getting incorrect values when adding/removing.

Comment: When you do your filter (removing account) you're using `this.props.account[i]`, but the `i` in that is based on `this.props.products.arrangements.items`, not `this.props.account`, so that could be causing a mismatch.  Also if you assign `this.props.xxx` to a variable and then edit properties of the variable, that's the same as trying to edit `this.props.xxx` directly (not sure if that's causing the issue, but something to watch out for).  Check out the edit (second half) of my answer, that might help - I would use ADD_ACCOUNT and REMOVE_ACCOUNT actions (with one acct at a time) for clarity.

Comment: You were right there was a mismatch - the main issue came from the fact that I was adding/removing entries from the array but then comparing that new array (which would have less entries) to this.props.products.arrangements.items.map((item,i). So I changed my logic - instead of removing/adding entries, I added "isSelected" to account[] which I update. I updated my code in my question.